# SPARK : Filter or Where returns extra results when applied on a DataFrame.LIMIT()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe (df1) of 1000+ rows of schema :

```
+--------+-------------+-------------------+
|      id|       pro_id|           datetime|
+--------+-------------+-------------------+
|11304569|      8195360|2015-01-23 15:21:51|
|11334963|      8060212|2015-01-28 22:49:17|
+--------+-------------+-------------------+
```

After applying :

```
val df2 = df1.limit(10)
println(" no of df2 : "+ df2.count())
df2.show()
```

Gives result :

> ```
>  no of df2 : 10
> +--------+-------------+-------------------+
> |      id|       pro_id|           datetime|
> +--------+-------------+-------------------+
> |11304569|      8195360|2015-01-23 15:21:51|
> |11334963|      8060212|2015-01-28 22:49:17|
> |11334963|      8060212|2015-01-28 22:49:17|
> |11334963|      8060212|2015-01-28 23:20:43|
> |11304569|      8143638|2015-02-03 14:34:48|
> |11336154|      8060212|2015-02-03 19:25:24|
> |11304569|      8173052|2015-02-05 08:15:12|
> |11398902|      8173052|2015-02-05 08:18:50|
> |11349129|      8097653|2015-02-05 08:29:33|
> |11349129|      8027845|2015-02-05 08:29:33|
> +--------+-------------+-------------------+
> ```

then applied the filter function

```
val v = df2.filter($"datetime" >= "2015-02-03 00:00:00")
println(" no of v : "+ v.count())
v.show()
```

This should give me just the LAST 6 rows , but instead 
It gave :

> ```
>  no of v : 10
> +--------+-------------+-------------------+
> |      id|       pro_id|           datetime|
> +--------+-------------+-------------------+
> |11304569|      8143638|2015-02-03 14:34:48|
> |11336154|      8060212|2015-02-03 19:25:24|
> |11304569|      8173052|2015-02-05 08:15:12|
> |11398902|      8173052|2015-02-05 08:18:50|
> |11349129|      8097653|2015-02-05 08:29:33|
> |11349129|      8027845|2015-02-05 08:29:33|
> |11349129|      8105806|2015-02-05 08:29:33|
> |11349187|      8197725|2015-02-05 09:00:32|
> |11349188|      8134473|2015-02-05 08:01:50|
> |11349187|      8132574|2015-02-05 09:09:07|
> +--------+-------------+-------------------+
> ```

How am I getting the extra 4 rows from the original df1, when i am not even linking the df1 in  anyway  ?

Does the "LIMIT" function work in some other way ?

Comment: That should work; once your `df2` was created, it should only have 10 rows in it such that your `v` DataFrame should have only given you 6 rows.  Could you provide the data for a potential repro?    Here's an [example](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/dennyglee/databricks/blob/master/notebooks/Users/denny%40databricks.com/scratch/test-scala.html) using my own data following your code example.

Comment: @DennyLee ,I have a bit of doubt , you have retrieved the 'df' from mysql's limit, which gives you exactly 10 rows,

can you take 20 or 30 rows in 'df' and try?

Comment: I'm not quite following this - the query in the example is against a 1.4M row table in Spark SQL - MySQL isn't involved here (i.e. Df has 1.4M rows).  Are you asking that I rewrite in my example 'Val df2 = df.limit(30)'?